# Help me identify the hex-to-allen adapter in this image

Tags: adapter

I'm trying to determine the name of the red-circled adapter so that I can buy it and replicate this setup to fix something at my place.

[image: Unknown Adapter that is female-hex-to-female-hex]

Comment: Hmm the similar tool I use is a hex bit ratchet(ratchet with screwdriver socket, not to be confused with a ratchet*ing* screwdriver or a standard ratchet with a hex bit adapter).  Many socket sets include a hex bit adapter, although that's not as compact.  That said, are you certain what is pictured is an adapter and not just welded to the allan key?

Comment: get something like this ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=hex+bit+ratchet&iax=images&ia=images&iai=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.infar.com.tw%2Fproimages%2Fpb%2F5-9_Socket_Sets%2F9-7.jpg

Answer (score 5):

This is a 1/4" x 1/4" hex adapter. Sizes will vary depending on the allen wrench used.

[image]

Instead of using this, you could get an offset screwdriver: slotted on one side, Phillips on the other.

[image]